# Smoking weed in Amsterdam as a tourist

Tags: netherlands, amsterdam, drugs, smoking

I read the following question and all its answers:

[Is weed still legal for tourists in Amsterdam?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12942/is-weed-still-legal-for-tourists-in-amsterdam/12943#12943)

I am not even a weed smoker, but since I am going to Amsterdam, I thought I'd give it a try. I would just like to know **how** to be able to do it, since I don't quite understand if you *really* need a weed pass when going to a coffee-shop or not. I also don't understand if 3 years after the question/answer the situation has changed.

Comment: It's still legal (if you're the above right age) and you can get it in Amsterdam as a tourist, but I'm not sure if you can get it in ALL the shops as a tourist. I know for example that in the cities near the border with other countries (like Breda, Tilburg, ...) you cannot buy it as a foreigner.

Comment: I think you are using the word "legal" in a different way... But I get what you are saying. I'm only interested in Amsterdam, since I am going precisely there.
So *there is* the need to have a card but *not all the shops will check it* ?

Comment: It is still ILLEGAL, but as before not acted upon. You will need a passport, or European ID, and need to be 18 or over. Usually having/smoking weed is not a problem, but if you are arrested for something else, having weed is not going to help you.

Comment: *"I would just like to **know** to be able to do it"*... I don't get it, do you think it's some kind of useful skill that you have to learn or something?

Comment: Note that you might fail drug tests afterwards, for quite some time.

Comment: If you do not use weed at home, why do it when in Amsterdam, it is as illegal and there is no need for it at all!

Comment: Also note that depending on the country that you're coming from, this could land you in trouble back home. Many nations have it written in to law that if you do something illegal abroad that is illegal at home, you can and will be (if they find out) charged just the same back home.

Comment: @Mehrdad : you forgot the "how" in the quoted sentence. That answers your comment

Comment: My top tip - visit Getto. The nachos are great and the Appletinis are intensely good. Who needs weed when you are hammered in a gay bar :D

Comment: @All: Yes, I am aware that doing something illegal (in my country smoking is NOT illegal, selling drugs is) may get you in trouble, yes I am aware that I might fail drug tests afterwards. I appreciate your care for me, but I would still like to try it.

Comment: @Noldor130884: That was a typo, it doesn't really answer my comment... in fact it makes the question even more obvious. You want to know how to smoke or obtain weed? What benefit do you see in either of those? Are you worried someone will hold a gun to your head one day and kill you if you refuse to smoke weed?

Comment: @Mehrdad: I don't want to argue, but there is a question linked which speaks about coffee-shops, and since it is not possible (nor I want to) to speak about illegal things on this forum, I think that yours is just misjudgement. I think it's pretty clear that I wanted to know how to smoke in Amsterdam without doing something I can be prosecuted for and by following Dutch rules.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire unless you are talking about child abuse, prosecuting stuff done abroad (which is legal abroad) sounds like something done by regimes, not democracies.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I'm not talking about people abusing kids abroad. Why should it be okay for something to be illegal at home, but OK to run off and do it somewhere else? You're a visitor, you're not a citizen when you visit a foreign land. Me for example I'm a Canadian, so regardless of where I travel, I'm expected to conduct myself like a Canadian, and that means following Canadian law. That's the principle, has nothing to do with regimes.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire absolutely not. If an American person aged 20 comes to Europe and drinks a beer, no US authority is entitled to charge him/her for illegal drinking because it is *not* illegal to drink in Europe when you are 20 and the US does not have jurisdiction in Europe. No wonder why in my country (Italy) the only crime for which you can be tried even if committed abroad is child abuse. I expect any **sane** democracy to have similar rules.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What the law currently says is that "coffee shops" are only allowed to sell cannabis to people residing in the Netherlands (*ingezetenencriterium*) and can check that by asking a proof of registration from a Dutch municipality (together with a valid ID). This rule has replaced the "weed pass" concept, which has been abandoned, and is in principle valid nationwide.

However, it's up to the municipalities to integrate this new rule in their local "coffee shop policy" and coordinate with the police and the public prosecutor to enforce it. As of [mid-2015](https://www.rijksoverheid.nl/actueel/nieuws/2015/07/01/ingezetenencriterium-in-meer-coffeeshopgemeenten-onderdeel-van-beleid), most municipalities in the Netherlands did so and municipalities in the south (which drove the reform in the first place) seem especially aggressive in enforcing it (I saw media reports about police raids and coffee shop closures).

But Amsterdam most certainly did not, and various press reports suggest that it first agreed to close coffee shops that were too close to schools intead of implementing the new rule and then decided to postpone that while waiting for a court decision. The justice minister also went on record (in 2012, as the new rules were introduced) stating that the ministry would not try to enforce the residency rule in Amsterdam on its own and could not specify when it would be implemented.

As a practical matter, in Amsterdam, as of Spring 2016, you can buy whatever you want and smoke on the premises without any problem, no questions asked. Personally, I do not smoke and obviously cannot vouch that each and every shop will serve you but that's what I have observed and I can't imagine shops would restrict purchases unless the municipality forces them to. You can also buy weed as a tourist in The Hague (and, I think, Rotterdam and Utrecht) but they tend to be stricter with regards to other products like space cakes.

Comment: +1. @OP note that they will ask for your ID (passport, driving license, etc) even if you look like an obvious foreigner.

Comment: So you're saying you can be Relaxed without drugs? +1 for that! :)

Comment: kudos on the use of the word "razzias" glad I looked it up before correcting it!

Answer (score 1):

just walk into the coffee shop, you will know which ones will be selling weed it will be painfully obvious, go up to the counter and say

'alright mate can i have some kush and coffee'

Sit down and he will bring it to you, pretty simple

Answer (score 1):

I was in Amsterdam 3 months ago, and I had no problem to buy and smoke weed in a coffeeshop and I was in several coffeeshops ;)

I was also in Rotterdam and Den Haag and even there it wasn't a problem.